# Do calculations on numbers in 1 multiline textView and return result replacing numbers

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I am very new to android programming and am trying to complete my first app. It is a recipe converter.

I have stored my recipe details in a SQLite DB and the text for ingredients is just one multiline string separated by carriage returns. I have used a cursor to get the ingredient data into a textview which returns text like (could be numerous variants):

100ml Water
500 g Mince
2 x 400g can crushed tomatoes

etc.

I originally had each Qty, Unit and Ingredient Description stored separately in the database which made life easy when converting but I chose to store it in a multiline string to allow copying and pasting of ingredients from the internet or another source.

I am attempting to extract the numbers and then multiply them by a percentage, then return the new converted numbers, and the corresponding unit and description to get something like this:

(multiplied by 200%)

200ml Water
1000g Mince
4 x 400g can crushed tomatoes

I just don't know how to do it though. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have tried to do something like this to get the numbers.

public void Split() {
        TextView tvSplit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSplit);

```
    final TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    String s = tvTest.getText().toString();

    for (int i =0;i <= tvTest.getLineCount();i++){

        tvSplit.setText("");


        String text = s.replaceAll("\\D+", ",");
        tvSplit.append(text);
        tvSplit.append("\n");

    }
```

That shows me all of the numbers with a "," between them but it also includes all numbers in the string like in the above example prior to conversion it would show 100,500,2,400 when I only need 100,500,2. Then from that point I'm not sure how I would convert them all. My "fresh to programming mind" thought that I could store these in a temp SQL table by INSERT INTO tablename (id, originalvalues) VALUES (my string ie 100,500,2).

I could then pull them back out, do the calculation, update the table, then add them back into my textview with the remaining string. I haven't got that far yet, so I'm just wondering what the correct way to do it is.

UPDATE 2:

As per my comments, this is the code I used to show an alert dialog with each item listed on a separate line, I then used the selected line to find the number before any " " to then display the text on the screen.

public void PopUpSpinnerDialogue() {

```
    final TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

    final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest2);

    String s = tvTest.getText().toString();


    final ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.my_dropdown_style, s.split("\n"));



    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Please choose the key ingredient you need to scale your recipe by.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setAdapter(myAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    try {
                        String itemName = myAdapter.getItem(which).toString();

                        String[] parts = itemName.split(" ");

                        String itemNumStr = parts[0];

                        TextView tvLineName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIngredientSelect);
                        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRecipeQtyConvert);
                        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQtyHave);

                        tvLineName.setText(itemName);


                        String b4Space = itemNumStr.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
                        tv2.setText(b4Space);
                        et1.setText(b4Space);
                        et2.setText(b4Space);

                        calculateKeyIngredientPercent();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(SelectConvertMethod.this, "Your ingredient must have a QTY. eg. 100ml.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            });
    android.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

It is this idea that I think I can use but I don't know how to code it and then display the results.

UPDATE 3:

The code or at least the idea of the code I am trying to use is this.

TextView tvSplit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSplit);

```
    final TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    String s = tvTest.getText().toString();


    for (int i =0;i <= tvTest.getLineCount();i++){
    String[] ingreds = s.split("\n");
        tvSplit.setText("");

        String[] parts = ingreds.split(" ");

        String Qty = parts[0];
        String Units = parts[1];
        String Ingredients = parts[2];

        Integer QtyInt = Integer.parseInt(Qty);}
```

ingreds.split doesn't work and also, I don't know how to specify splitting the parts for each i.

Comment: Please post code of what you already tried

Comment: Please see the update in the post.

Comment: Nice thing you have here :) We need more info: You posted the string '100ml Water 500 g Mince 2 x 400g can crushed tomatoes' - do you parse it exactly like that? Or yoy have spaces between 400 ang "g" ? Also does user at any point have to see the parsed string or it will be shown only after splitting?

Comment: I apologise for my lack of knowledge regarding the technical lingo but whatever the user puts into my EditText which gets added to my SQL table. It means the user could put a space or they may not put a space between 400 and "g". I am definitely hoping they put a space between "g" and "Ingredient Description" but I don't know how to force it. Logically though, when a user would enter list of ingredients they would put a space between them. If I can limit what a user enters in an EditText to force a space between the Qty and Unit (400 and "g") but if not, I have to assume they'll do either.

Comment: So the textView shows the text like "400g Water"+"\n"+"400 g Water"+"\n". Does that make sense? Also, the user would only have to see the text once it is converted and I add it to an alert dialog as a dropdown list. I will then use the same theory as I would here to convert it further by other parameters. I hope I answered your question?

Comment: Yeah its clear. The problem is that it will be hard to know what numbers are the amount and what are description of the product. For eample 4 x 400g can means in reality 4 cans of 400g of product. What I would do is to redo the input/textboxes for a user so you would have a textbox for an amount and the combobox for a list with "ml, oz, g, kg". Then you could easly combine it to the string and parse it and would always know if there is a space between "400" and a "g". Also it would allow you to set different marker then a space. Or are you using one textbox for whole input?

Comment: Aslo: never hope that user will do something you intended. It will be always other way :)

Comment: I did have separate boxes in my first prototype of this app, the problem I had was I want the user to be able to copy and paste data into one textbox for ease on their part. Otherwise they need to enter each one separately. I have seen apps or programs on the web that can do the conversion that I want to do, for example this website [link](http://mykitchencalculator.com/recipeconverter.html). It is that idea that I want to bring to my app.

Comment: I was hoping there might be some sort of code I can write that says "return the number before any space" where the number is at the start of the line. I have managed to split the number like this in another section of my app using code I will update in my original question.

Comment: Ok. If you look into the manual: http://www.mykitchencalculator.com/howtouserecipeconverter.html you will see how they solved it. They have a format for a recipe (quantity, units, product) and this way you can use space as a separator and use only first number as a base for multiplication. Alsothey use ## marker to mark number for additional multiplication). This way you really need only to look for a first and second space and not use "x" in "4 x 100g". It has to be "4 100g"

Comment: Good pick up @ŁukaszMotyczka . Is there a way that I can show an error in my EditText if this format is not followed? Then if it is in the correct format do you think what I want to achieve is possible? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ad. error: some cases you can pick up like that you do not have number (quantity) at the first place (for example user puts "water 1l").
Ad possibility: Of course. Split your text by looking for a first space in the string - you will have a quantity and the product. Change first string into int and than you can do rest. 
PS: Check if the "number" string contains special characters like 1/2, 3/4 and so on to change them into decimas

Comment: PS2: the website you posted do not allow for "100ml water" it has to be 100 ml water" to work so they are using idea I described

Comment: Thanks. I can get around the text input then. So as for stripping out the number, then converting it, do you think the best way is to do it via the way I thought? eg. Insert the values into a table as separate lines, convert them and then user a query to display them, then append the unit and item description back on them? Or is there a better method to do that without putting them into a temp sql table?

Comment: I just saw your other responses. I will try that probably tomorrow and let you know how I go. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I think you might not need sql table for that. I would split the string by nextline marker, then I would split every line to find the amount number. Mulitply this number and add it back to resulting string. But your way might also work

Comment: That ultimately what I'd like to do. I just don't know what code I need to split strings that have already been split for an X number of lines. I have been trying a FOR LOOP but I can't get it working.

Comment: Post a code you are trying to achieve this with :)

Comment: Will do so in the question under Update 3

Comment: Sorry, have to go, ill get to it later :)

Comment: Not a worry, I have to go also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regex. It allowed the data to be entered with or without a space. So I ended up using this code to pull out the Qty of each line, multiply it by a percentage, append the text (units,ingredient description) to the line, then add it to a string array, to add to my alert dialog.

Code is here.

```
public void Split() {

    final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest2);
    TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    TextView tvPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPercent);

    String tvP = tvPercent.getText().toString();
    String tvNumOnly = tvP.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    Integer PercentVal = Integer.parseInt(tvNumOnly);
    String s = tvTest.getText().toString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\d*) ?(.*)(?:\\n*))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {

        String Qty = m.group(2) + ".00";
        String Ingred = m.group(3);

        Float QtyFloat = Float.parseFloat(Qty);

        Float newQTY = (QtyFloat * PercentVal) / 100;

        String newQTYstr = newQTY.toString();


        sb.append(newQTYstr + " " + Ingred + "\n");
    }

    String[] lines = sb.toString().split("\n");

    String[] IngredArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 0, lines.length - 1);

    final ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.my_dropdown_style, IngredArray);


    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Please choose the key ingredient you need to scale your recipe by.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setAdapter(myAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    try {
                        String itemName = myAdapter.getItem(which).toString();

                        String[] parts = itemName.split(" ");

                        String itemNumStr = parts[0];

                        TextView tvLineName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIngredientSelect);
                        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRecipeQtyConvert);
                        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQtyHave);

                        tvLineName.setText(itemName);


                        String b4Space = itemNumStr.replaceAll("\\D.\\D+", "");
                        tv2.setText(b4Space);
                        et1.setText(b4Space);
                        et2.setText(b4Space);

                        calculateKeyIngredientPercent();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(SelectConvertMethod.this, "Your ingredient must have a QTY. eg. 100ml.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            });
    android.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

//        Toast.makeText(SelectConvertMethod.this, sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
}
```